# Error adding library dependency hosted on github packages

Tags: flutter, kotlin, build.gradle, github-package-registry, github-token

I'm studying Flutter and trying to integrate Trust Wallet services into my app. I imported the `trust_wallet_core` package from pub.dev (https://pub.dev/packages/trust_wallet_core), and while starting the app, I received an error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform wallet-core-3.1.27.aar (com.trustwallet:wallet-core:3.1.27) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download wallet-core-3.1.27.aar (com.trustwallet:wallet-core:3.1.27)
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core/com/trustwallet/wallet-core/3.1.27/wallet-core-3.1.27.aar'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core/com/trustwallet/wallet-core/3.1.27/wallet-core-3.1.27.aar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

With this error at hand, I started to look at their repository documentation (https://developer.trustwallet.com/developer/wallet-core/integration-guide/android-guide). The documentation explains creating a GitHub personal access token and importing this configuration into your `build.gradle`, which is exactly what I did.

Inside my Android folder, I inserted the expected configuration in `build.gradle` to access the local.properties variables correctly, but I'm still getting the same error.

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTDNJ.png)

The build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "br.com.coders.concept.crypto_digital_bank"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.coders.concept.crypto_digital_bank"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")
}

def gprUser = localProperties.getProperty("gpr.user")
def gprToken = localProperties.getProperty("gpr.token")
println "gpr.user: $gprUser"
println "gpr.token: $gprToken"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core"
            credentials {
                username gprUser
                password gprToken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is something I missed or did wrong?

I tried:

- Generated another key with more access, not just readonly.
- Changed the approach and imported the GitHub path directly into the pubspec.yaml.
- Generated a new access key on GitHub.
- Deleted the entire project and started a new one with only these configurations to see what happens.
- Duplicated the local.properties file from the Android folder to the root project folder.
- Inserted the authentication settings in all the Gradle project files.

What I expect:

- I expect to be able to access the dependency on GitHub Packages and use it within the project normally. However, I always receive a 401 error from this repository.